# Does "dirty electricity" cause cancer?

Tags: medical-science, safety, electromagnetism, cancer

> Research by Magda Havas, Ph.D., of Trent University in Canada, and U.S. epidemiologist Samuel Milham, M.D., links something called “dirty electricity” with diabetes, malignant melanoma, and cancers of the breast, thyroid, uterus and lung. Dirty electricity is an industry term that describes a multi-frequency exposure when higher frequencies like RF couple with the lower frequencies running along power lines.
>
> BPL (Broadband-Over-Power-Lines) is 100% dirty electricity — that’s how it functions — and people barraged by it can now measure RF radiation emanating from their light sockets.

—[DOCUMENTATION on Issues Regarding the installation of Smart Meters](http://www.bantexassmartmeters.com/2012/documentation-issues-installation-smart-meters/)

Is any of this supported by evidence?

- Do these people have the qualifications claimed here?
- Do these people claim what is summarised?
- Will "dirty electricity" cause cancer?
- Can people "measure RF radiation emanating from their light sockets"?

Comment: A quick note: BPL seems to be an inferior technology compared to optical fiber broadband.  Here in SE Tennessee, gigabit fiber is run to the home along the electric poles by the electric utility. So it is not necessarily the case that a smart electric meter needs to run off of BPL internet because other internet technology may be available at the smart meter.

Comment: On RFI from BPL, in the USA the Amateur Radio Relay League (ARRL) has been against BPL because it has potential to increase the HF noise floor and/or generate signals interfering with HF communications. The ARRL has lobbied the FCC and even litigated against it, and probably for good reason.  But blocking a weak distress call from getting through, or interfering with hobby communications, is different from being at such a high level that it would cause cancer, which would itself be news because as far as I'm aware a firm link has not been established.

Comment: One way to measure RF around your home, tune an AM radio to a frequency with no station, you will hear just static. Place the AM radio near something noisy, and you will hear it. This only works if tbe noise source is broadbanded (such as something that arcs a lot like the brushes on an old sewing machine or power tool motor) or has energy at the particular freq you used on the radio.  Also an AM radio typically contains a directional bar antenna, so you need to do some rotation.  FM is much less susceptible.

Comment: Very closely related to this question (duplicate?): http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6831/do-compact-fluorescent-lamps-cfl-create-dirty-electricity-which-can-impact-hea

Comment: In fact, we've had a number of different questions which question EMF. Assuming that all the the claims are bunk, I wonder if it is possible to create a master question with a killer answer to cover all of them?

Comment: Well, they claim different diseases. Furthermore the means of EMF interaction varies: "dirty" electricity, microwave radiation, etc... My question would be: is it possible to address all of these different claims in a single authoritative answer? Can we say that EM fields, in whatever variety, don't cause any ailment? Of course not... Solar light burns retinas, x-rays cause cancer, microwaves cook eggs... etc. etc.

Comment: @Oddthinking Perhaps one could claim that for any frequency below visible light, the only effect on the human body is to heat it. A question could be centred on a claim such as, [To date, the only health effect from RF fields identified in scientific reviews has been related to an increase in body temperature (> 1 °C) from exposure at very high field intensity found only in certain industrial facilities, such as RF heaters.](http://www.who.int/peh-emf/publications/facts/fs304/en/index.html).

Comment: See also more EMF-related documents at http://www.who.int/peh-emf/publications/factsheets/en/index.html which show some exceptions to that rule: for example, [There are established biological effects from acute exposure at high levels (well above 100 µT) that are explained by recognized biophysical mechanisms. External ELF magnetic fields induce electric fields and currents in the body which, at very high field strengths, cause nerve and muscle stimulation and changes in nerve cell excitability in the central nervous system.](http://www.who.int/peh-emf/publications/facts/fs322/en/index.html)

Comment: Your 4th point: yes, it can be measured. Not with the human body, but with antenna's. HAM operators can often detect lousy Power Line Ethernet circuits a couple of houses away.

Comment: The link to the source is now invalid. Moreover, Magda Havas has a track record of dodgy claims and studies in this area *and* a commercial interest in selling "solutions". That should be a big hint that her work is not a reliable source of evidence. See the [related question](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6831/do-compact-fluorescent-lamps-cfl-create-dirty-electricity-which-can-impact-hea?lq=1).