# Mobile towers pose serious hazards?

Tags: environmental-health, mobile-phones, microwaves

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do mobile phones have anything to do with brain cancer?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/569/do-mobile-phones-have-anything-to-do-with-brain-cancer)

Today we had a seminar about wireless technologies and were told that mobile towers pose serious health hazards. I found this related article on web: http://www.merinews.com/article/mobile-towers-pose-serious-health-hazards/15853828.shtml. Is there any truth in this claim? Has it been scientifically proven?

Comment: [These](http://www.slideshare.net/nehakumar01/cell-phone-and-mobile-tower-radiation-hazards) were the slides that we were shown. (Note: I was with the OP).

Comment: Also related: [Can microwave ovens give you cancer?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/552/can-microwave-ovens-give-you-cancer) Basically, all the speculative calculations in that presentation are irrelevant because those frequencies of radiation have no ionizing radiation impact

Comment: Another area to read up on EM is here:  http://forums.randi.org/showthread.php?t=220403  A few electrical engineers have weighed in on that thread.

Comment: It doesn't really look like a duplicate to me.

Comment: We were also told in the seminar that one should not use phone for more than 6 minutes a day, or else it could affect health adversely. Is there any truth in that statement?

Comment: They seem to cause ICD-10 F22 in case of people opposing them

Comment: @vartec - ROFL. Explanation for Vartec's crypitic comment: http://www.icd10data.com/ICD10CM/Codes/F01-F99/F20-F29/F22-/F22